# Get array of different directives in order

Tags: angular

I want to grab some directives from the view (or content) in the same order in which they were specified in the template.

## Attempt 1 [[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OHSXhKhpEJKCXXaytFZ9?p=preview)]

```
@Directive({selector: 'dir-1'}) class Dir1 {}
@Directive({selector: 'dir-2'}) class Dir2 {}
@Directive({selector: 'dir-3'}) class Dir3 {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<dir-1></dir-1>
<dir-2></dir-2>
<dir-3></dir-3>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChildren(Dir1) dir1s;
  @ViewChildren(Dir2) dir2s;
  @ViewChildren(Dir3) dir3s;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.dir1s, this.dir2s, this.dir3s);
  }
}
```

By simply using different directives, I **lose their order**.

## Attempt 2 [[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xfDFGBe6kk6ai8vACnMF?p=preview)]

```
@Directive({selector: 'general'}) class General {}
@Directive({selector: '[specific-1]'}) class Specific1 {}
@Directive({selector: '[specific-2]'}) class Specific2 {}
@Directive({selector: '[specific-3]'}) class Specific3 {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<general specific-1></general>
<general specific-2></general>
<general specific-3></general>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChildren(General) generals;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.generals);
  }
}
```

By having a "general" selector, I **no longer know the type of the directive**.

Comment: Do you want to get `Specific1, Specific2, Specific3`?

Comment: Yes, I want the resulting array to contain objects of specific types in the correct order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documentation said https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#find-a-parent-component-by-injection

> Obtaining a component reference is a bit tricky in Angular.

So you can try the following trick:

```
export abstract class BaseSpecific { }

const provideSpecific = (component: BaseSpecific) => {
  return { provide: BaseSpecific, useExisting: forwardRef(() => component) };
};

@Directive({ selector: '[specific-1]', providers: [provideSpecific(Specific1)] }) export class Specific1 implements BaseSpecific { }
@Directive({ selector: '[specific-2]', providers: [provideSpecific(Specific2)] }) export class Specific2 implements BaseSpecific { }
@Directive({ selector: '[specific-3]', providers: [provideSpecific(Specific3)] }) export class Specific3 implements BaseSpecific { }

@Directive({ selector: 'general' })
export class General {
  constructor(@Self() public specificClass: BaseSpecific) { }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <general specific-1></general>
    <general specific-2></general>
    <general specific-3></general>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChildren(General) generals: QueryList<General>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.generals.map(x => x.specificClass.constructor.name));
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/7czVVMGxhKG9QKlnAmzV?p=preview)**